# Wrong / nonfunctional serializable

Tags: java, android, serialization, deserialization

Hi I have a problem with simple serializable

Here are my all class. without getters, setters and try & catch

```
public class myTrip implements Serializable {
String NazovTripu;
int den, mesiac, rok;
String Mesto;
String filename="prve.dat";

public String getFilename() {
    return filename;
}

public void Serializuj(Context context){
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    fos = context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    os.writeObject(this);
    os.close();       
}

public myTrip DeSerializuj(Context context) {
    FileInputStream fis = null;       
        fis = context.openFileInput(filename);

    ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    myTrip mojtrip = (myTrip) is.readObject();
    is.close();
    fis.close();
        return mojtrip;        
    return null;
}

public void DeSerializuj2(Context context) {
    FileInputStream fis = null;

        fis = context.openFileInput(filename);

    ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    myTrip simpleClass = (myTrip) is.readObject();
    is.close();
    fis.close();

}
```

I have here two variants deserialize but no work, I don't know where are problem. if in serialize or deserialize, please help me :)

I use this in one activity

```
myTrip prvy= new myTrip();
    ...
    prvy.Serializuj(this);
```

and this code in OnCreate method other activity

```
myTrip prvy= new myTrip();
...
prvy.DeSerializuj(this);
```

Application doesn't crash, but varianles have no values.

Comment: This code does not compile. Post the real code. Get rid of `DeSerializuj2()`. It does nothing useful. It should return the deserialized object, in which case it would be identical to `DeSerializuj()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here are good serialization and deserialization code..

```
 public void Serializuj( myTrip serTrip){
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "data.dat");
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ObjectOutputStream ou = new ObjectOutputStream(fo);
        ou.writeObject(serTrip);
        ou.close();
        fo.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public myTrip DeSerializuj() {
    myTrip   prvy = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(getApplication().getFilesDir(), "data.dat");
        FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(file);
        ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(fi);
     prvy = (myTrip) oi.readObject();
        oi.close();
        fi.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return prvy;
}
```